# Add quotation at the start and end of each line in Notepad++

Tags: regex, text-editor, notepad++

I have a list (in a .txt file) which I'd like to quickly convert to JavaScript Syntax, so I want to take the following:

```
AliceBlue
AntiqueWhite
Aqua
Aquamarine
Azure
Beige
Bisque
Black
BlanchedAlmond
```

and convert it to an array literal...

```
var myArray = ["AliceBlue", "AntiqueWhite", ... ]
```

I have the list in notepad++ and I need a reg expression to add the `"` at the start of the line and `",` at the end and remove the line break... does anyone have a quick fix to do this? I'm terrible with RegEx.

I often have to perform such tasks so to know how to do this would be a great benefit to me. Many thanks

Answer (score 341, accepted):

You won't be able to do it in a single replacement; you'll have to perform a few steps. Here's how I'd do it:

1. Find (in regular expression mode):

   ```
   (.+)
   ```

   Replace with:

   ```
   "\1"
   ```

   This adds the quotes:

   ```
   "AliceBlue"
   "AntiqueWhite"
   "Aqua"
   "Aquamarine"
   "Azure"
   "Beige"
   "Bisque"
   "Black"
   "BlanchedAlmond"
   ```
2. Find (in extended mode):

   ```
   \r\n
   ```

   Replace with (with a space after the comma, not shown):

   ```
   ,
   ```

   This converts the lines into a comma-separated list:

   ```
   "AliceBlue", "AntiqueWhite", "Aqua", "Aquamarine", "Azure", "Beige", "Bisque", "Black", "BlanchedAlmond"
   ```
3. Add the `var myArray =` assignment and braces manually:

   ```
   var myArray = ["AliceBlue", "AntiqueWhite", "Aqua", "Aquamarine", "Azure", "Beige", "Bisque", "Black", "BlanchedAlmond"];
   ```

Comment: If you want to automate this, you can start recording a macro, then perform these steps.

Comment: Just before the "Find (in extended mode)step," verify/make the file end of line character (EOL) to UNIX format.  Do Edit->EOL Conversion->UNIX format.

Comment: On Windows, 2. Find (in extended mode): \r\n

Comment: @Rami A.: True, the source file might have been created in Windows so it would make sense to use Windows line endings. Note that 1) Notepad++ is Windows-only anyway, and even then, 2) that doesn't mean any file it opens will have Windows line endings.

Comment: Is the \1 option Notepad++ specific or is it standard for RegEx? Where do you find a list of these? I used this for a HTML <LI> menu and it was PERFECT! I would like to know some more possible tricks I could use.

Comment: This worked, but I had to search `[\r\n]` instead of `\r\n`

Comment: Since I just needed quotes at the start of each line I had to replace with this: "\1 (no trailing quote).

Comment: Strange. This did not work for me in VisualStudioCode. It replaced the entire emails with "\1" as a string replacement.

Answer (score 14):

- One simple way is replace \n(newline) with ","(double-quote comma double-quote) after this append double-quote in the start and end of file.

*example:*

```
      AliceBlue
      AntiqueWhite
      Aqua
      Aquamarine
      Beige
```

- Replcae \n with ","

  ```
    AliceBlue","AntiqueWhite","Aqua","Aquamarine","Beige
  ```
- Now append "(double-quote) at the start and end

  ```
   "AliceBlue","AntiqueWhite","Aqua","Aquamarine","Beige"
  ```

If your text contains blank lines in between you can use regular expression \n+ instead of \n

*example:*

```
      AliceBlue

      AntiqueWhite
      Aqua


      Aquamarine
      Beige
```

- Replcae \n+ with "," (in regex mode)

  ```
    AliceBlue","AntiqueWhite","Aqua","Aquamarine","Beige
  ```
- Now append "(double-quote) at the start and end

  ```
   "AliceBlue","AntiqueWhite","Aqua","Aquamarine","Beige"
  ```

Comment: I tried these steps but ended up with extra "," after the last line in text.

Answer (score 13):

In notepad++, for placing any thing before value

1. Press CTRL+H
2. Replace ^ with ' (sign you want append at the start)
3. Select search mode as Regular Expression
4. Click Replace All

In notepad++, for placing any thing After value

1. Press CTRL+H
2. Replace $ with ' (sign you want to append at the end)
3. Select search mode as Regular Expression
4. Click Replace All

Ex: After performing above steps
AHV01 replaced with 'AHV01'

Happy Learning!!

Thanks.

Comment: By far the easiest to implement and simplest to understand. I spent way too long on trying to get various regex' to work and all I needed was to split it into beginning of line and end of line and not bother with what was in between them.
You deserve a cookie!

Comment: Sweet and simple. I started by placing the cursor at the beginning of the first line and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 9):

1. Put your cursor at the begining of line 1.
2. click Edit>ColumnEditor. Put " in the text and hit enter.
3. Repeat 2 but put the cursor at the end of line1 and put ", and hit enter.

Comment: I have spaces in my line text like 'Action and Adventure' or 'musical & classical'. Now the step 1 worked but step 3 resulted in breaking the string and inserted double quote inside the string like this."Actio"n & Adventure

My original list look like this 

Anime
Children & Family
Action & Adventure
British
Classic & Cult
Classic
Comedies
Crime
Cult
Documentaries
Dramas
Horror
Independent
International
LGBTQ
Music & Classical
Reality
Romantic
Sci-Fi
Sports
Thrillers

I am using 64 bits Notepad++ v8.4.4

Answer (score 6):

I am using Notepad 8.1.9.2 64bit on Windows10, the replacement procedures can be finished in one step, try this:

Find what: (.+)\r\n

Replace with:    "\1",

Note: Wrap around and regular express option is selected.

And then you still need to add bracket manually in your code

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

- Place your cursor at the end of the text.
- Press <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> and <kbd>-></kbd>. The cursor will move to the next line.
- Press <kbd>CTRL-F</kbd> and type <kbd>,</kbd> in "Replace with:" and press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

You will need to put a quote at the beginning of your first text and the end of your last.