# add quotation at the end of the line if a specific string exists in the line with Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8849357/add-quotation-at-the-start-and-end-of-each-line-in-notepad) fantastic solution to add quotation at the start and end of each line. However, I would like some criteria to be met before doing it, that is, if the line starts with `"keyName":` then add a quotation at the end of the line so that I get `"mystring"`:

```
onestring,
"keyName": "mystring
otherstring
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i not have npp here, but it should be as easy as replacing any regular expression string.

select "regular expressions" in the search/replace dialog, and do something along the lines:

```
find string:  ^("keName".*)$

replace with:  \1"
```

or

```
replace with:  $1"
```

[Notepad++ Regex Backreference syntax in Search/Replace - \1 or $1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11970405/notepad-regex-backreference-syntax-in-search-replace-1-or-1)