# add quotes to each item in a text file

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I want to use [this list of bad words](https://github.com/LDNOOBW/List-of-Dirty-Naughty-Obscene-and-Otherwise-Bad-Words/blob/master/en) for my input filtering. It's a plain list right now, but I need to convert it to JSON for my server to use.

I don't want to go through each line and add quotes and a `,`. Is there a regex or fast way to add `" ",` to each line in a `txt` file?

Such that:

```
2g1c
2 girls 1 cup
acrotomophilia
alabama hot pocket
alaskan pipeline
```

Becomes

```
"2g1c",
"2 girls 1 cup",
"acrotomophilia",
"alabama hot pocket",
"alaskan pipeline",
...
```

Comment: What, like `output = '"' + input.replace(/\n/g, '","') + '"'` (assuming `input` is a string representing the whole file)? (Or make the replacement string `'",\n"'` if you still want newlines in the output, though if it's JSON presumably you don't need them though you would need to add `[` and `]` at the beginning and end.)

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8849357/add-quotation-at-the-start-and-end-of-each-line-in-notepad) SO question. It is a free program.

Comment: `fileContents.split('\n').map(line => '"' + line + '"').join(',\n')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **backtick** <kbd>`</kbd>

```
var txt=`2g1c
2 girls 1 cup
acrotomophilia
alabama hot pocket
alaskan pipeline`;

var arrayUntrimmed = txt.split("\n");

var array=arrayUntrimmed.map(function(a){return a.trim()});
```

(Note: This ECMAScript 6 feature supported from Firefox 34 and Chrome 41)

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is split the string at the new lines and drop the last item in the array (since it's empty).

```js
var txt = '2g1c\n2 girls 1 cup\nacrotomophilia\nalabama hot pocket\nalaskan pipeline\n';
var array = txt.split('\n').slice(0, -1);


console.log(array)
```

You can then use [`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) as a predicate method to find out if a given string contains one or more of the blacklisted words.

```js
var txt = '2g1c\n2 girls 1 cup\nacrotomophilia\nalabama hot pocket\nalaskan pipeline\n';
var array = txt.split('\n').slice(0, -1);

var input1 = 'not bad';
var input2 = 'An alaskan pipeline is quite creative...';

var input1HasBadWords = array.some(function (word) {
  return input1.indexOf(word) > -1;
});

var input2HasBadWords = array.some(function (word) {
  return input2.indexOf(word) > -1;
});

console.log('input1 is: ' + input1HasBadWords);
console.log('input2 is: ' + input2HasBadWords);
```

Your controller would look something like so:

```
const fs = require('fs');

app.post('/route', (req, res) => {
  fs.readFile('/etc/hosts', 'utf8', (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      res.sendStatus(500);
    }

    const badWords = data.split('\n').slice(0, -1);
    const hasBadWords = badWords.some((word) => {
       return req.body.input.indexOf(word) > -1;
    });

    if(hasBadWords) {
      res.send('Dirty mouth? Clean it with orbit!');
    } else {
      res.send('You are very polite');
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

http://pastebin.com/U5phzWUM

I guess the easiest way is to use a software for this. It took me 30 sec to do this with SublimeText

http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/selection

Answer (score 0):

You can use readline module. read and add quotes in each line.

readline: https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html