# how to convert text with numbers ""?

Tags: notepad++

I have a file with different texts 
example

```
3/3.324.jpg
5/5.015.png
4/4.156.jpg
random text
4/4. random
5/5.random
11/11.1555.jpg
```

How to convert to

```
"3/3.324.jpg"
"5/5.015.png"
"4/4.156.jpg"
random text
4/4. random
5/5.random
"11/11.1555.jpg"
```

Comment: You can use regex in notepad++.  See if this helps https://gerardnico.com/ide/notepad/replace#the_search_mode_options

Comment: See the accepted answer in this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8849357/add-quotation-at-the-start-and-end-of-each-line-in-notepad

Comment: Why `random text` doesn't become `"random text"`? Do you want to add quote only to image file? Are extensions allways `.jpg` or `.png`? Never `.jpeg` or `.gif` or any image extension? Are the filename **allways** digits, slash, digits, dot, digits, extension?

Comment: yes, i want to add " " only on a text which ends with .jpg or .png extension

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl + H and select regex search mode.

Regex:

```
(^.*\.(jpg|png))$
```

Replace with:

```
"$1"
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/2E0Ji2/1