# Add quotation to start and end of each line in Xcode

Tags: regex, xcode, replace, find

I have multiple lists (in a .txt file) which I'd like to quickly convert to an array. I've seen this question asked and answered here for Notepad++, but not for Xcode. Is it possible to similarly here?

```
AliceBlue
AntiqueWhite
Aqua
Aquamarine
Azure
Beige
Bisque
Black
BlanchedAlmond
```

and convert it to an array literal...

```
var myArray = ["AliceBlue", "AntiqueWhite", ... ]
```

//the highest rated answer for this on the notepad++ thread: [Add quotation at the start and end of each line in Notepad++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8849357/add-quotation-at-the-start-and-end-of-each-line-in-notepad)
[image]

*I should add* I can use the expression (.+) in the find function, but not the "\1".

Answer (score 0):

To add quotation marks to the start and end of every line with regular expressions in Xcode, choose the “Regular expression” search option and use a search regex of `^.*$` to “capture” the whole line (i.e., `^` is the start of the line, `.*` is zero or more of any character, and `$` is the end of the line). You can then use a replacement regex of `"$0"` (i.e., a quotation mark, followed by capture group number zero, which was the original line, followed by a final quotation mark):

[image]

---

You can also use “multiple cursors”, a.k.a. multi-cursors. You can, for example, hold down the <kbd>⌥</kbd> key and click-drag with your mouse, and then hit <kbd>⌘</kbd>-<kbd>◀︎</kbd> to go to the start of the lines, <kbd>"</kbd> for the opening quotation mark, <kbd>⌘</kbd>-<kbd>▶︎</kbd> to go to the end of the lines, and <kbd>"</kbd> for the closing quotation mark.

[image]

And while you can hold <kbd>⌥</kbd> and and click-drag to make a bunch of multi-cursors, you can also toggle individual ones on and off with <kbd>⇧</kbd>-<kbd>⌃</kbd>-clicks.

---

If you want to remove the newline characters, too, with the regex approach, after doing the regex replacement, just go back to a normal “Contains” search and replace the “line break”, ⏎, with a comma and space:

[image]

Or, with the multi-cursor approach, after adding the quotation marks, go to the end of the line, add the comma and space, and hit the <kbd>⌦</kbd> key to delete the line breaks:

[image]

You just need to delete the trailing comma at the very end.

---

Obviously, no regex or multi-cursors are required when searching for line breaks. Just do a normal find-and-replace, replacing ⏎ with whatever you want, and then clean up the first and last entry:

[image]

Comment: FWIW, Paul Hudson has a lovely series of Xcode tricks and tips, https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLuoeXyslFTuYQ9Hoh42Bw8sPYMlTOV0V7. Regex searching is #1 on that playlist. Multiple cursors is #32.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like it's not possible to use Regular Expressions to replace in Xcode.
I ended up using Atom text editor to get this done, and the following expressions:

Find:

```
(\n+)
```

Replace:

```
",\r\n"
```

Comment: FWIW, atom is being [sunsetted](https://github.blog/2022-06-08-sunsetting-atom/). Good alternatives include [Sublime Text](https://sublimetext.com) or [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com) (amongst others).

Comment: Also, as an aside, in macOS, we generally do not use `\r\n`, but rather just `\n`. Windows uses the CR LF convention, but in macOS, it is generally just LF.